# Multiple router-outlets and fxHide/fxShow: why does it break my routing?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-flex-layout, router-outlet

I'm on an Angular 7 project with Angular Flex layout. On desktop view I have a tabs navigation and a sidenav on mobile. I use fxHide and fxShow to display the right nav. But as long as two router-outlets are here, my routing is broken, either on desktop or mobile. If the routing isn't working on desktop, I have to comment the mobile outlet and vice versa.

fxHide sets the display to none, so why does the hidden outlet has effect?

I can't use named outlets since my navs share the same routes, plus it messed up the urls.

I have reproduced my problem in a Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaejkr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&view=preview

app.component.html

```
<a fxHide fxShow.gt-xs="true" routerLink="hello">desktop-nav</a>
<a fxShow fxHide.gt-xs="true" routerLink="hello">mobile-nav</a>

<div class="desktop" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs="true">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="mobile" fxShow fxHide.gt-xs="true">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "hello", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "hello", component: HelloComponent }
];
```

Comment: Why do you need to have two router outlets? If you can explain this I will try to help. Also, note that your stackblitz is not the same as the code you have pasted here...can you update so they are consistent pls.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two router outlets for this case as it doesn't make sense to have a separate route for desktop versus mobile (or other responsive breakpoints).

I have [an example Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-tabs-sidenav?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) that shows how to set up a SideNav (`lt-md`) and tabs (`gt-sm`) using dynamic JSON routing/menu data.

You don't specify if your SideNav is permanently open on mobile, but even if the `mat-sidenav` is persistent or temporary and not displayed, your UI would still be displayed within the `mat-sidenav-container`.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #appDrawer mode="over" opened="false">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <app-menu-list-item *ngFor="let item of navItems[0].children[1].children" [item]="item">
      </app-menu-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <app-top-nav fxHide.xs [navItems]="navItems[0].children[1].children"></app-top-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Then in the `app-top-nav` here, you can either display the toolbar with the menu button for opening the `mat-sidenav` or the `md-tabs` using responsive `fxHide` attributes:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z1" fxHide.gt-sm>
  <button mat-icon-button id="menu" (click)="navService.openNav()">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>Dynamic Expanding Nav Drawer Example</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar backgroundColor="primary" fxHide.lt-md>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navItems"
     [routerLink]="link.route"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
     <mat-icon class="routeIcon">{{link.iconName}}</mat-icon>&nbsp;
    {{link.displayName}}
  </a>
</nav>
```